# Upper bound for $\sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} {n \choose i} (1 - \varepsilon)^i\varepsilon^{n-i}$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

What is tight upper and lower bound for following expression where $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ and $1\leq k \leq n$.

$\sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} {n \choose i} (1 - \varepsilon)^i\varepsilon^{n-i}$

Comment: That sum is just a value. It is a function of $\epsilon$ and $k$ and $n$. Tight bound over which variable?? $\epsilon$? $k$? or $n$?

Comment: If it's $\epsilon$, then lower bound = $0$ if $k < n$ and $1$ if $k = n$.

Comment: It may help to know that the sum can be expressed in terms of the incomplete beta function: $I_{1 - \varepsilon } (n - k + 1,k)$.

Comment: There is also an exact expression in terms of the gaussian hypergeometric function,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X \sim bin(n,\varepsilon)$ then
$$
 \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} {n \choose i} (1 - \varepsilon)^i\varepsilon^{n-i} =\mathbb{P}(X\leq k-1) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X\geq k-1).
$$
Usually, a common approach is to use the [Chernoff inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound), which provides pretty good upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 2):

For a simpler solution, use the appximation to $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n^{k}}{k!}$, then the summand becomes
$$
(1-\varepsilon)^n \frac{n^{i}\varepsilon^{i}(1-\varepsilon)^{-i}}{i!}
$$
then the upper bound can be easily found by using partial Taylor series expansion for the exponential function:
$$
S_{n} \leq(1-\varepsilon)^{n}\exp\bigg(\frac{n \varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}\bigg)
$$